# Two unique keys in SQL table

Tags: mysql, sql, json

I have a table

```
Users (Id, Uid, Name, Sex...).
```

`Id` is auto increment, `Uid` is unique, generated by my script (combination of caps and nubers, `2X4TY`).

The `Uid` is public, I'm using it in the URLs, in client-server communication via JSONs etc. I created it also to hide the internal `Id` which would otherwise tell people how many users I have.

I found myself using the `Uid` all the time and even started to use it as a FK in other tables. Is it a good way to do it? Shouldn't I send `Uid` via JSON, then locate the internal/auto-increment `Id` and work with it? It's more work and I'm confused.

Maybe I simply don't need any auto-increment `Id` but I was taught at uni that it's better all tables to have a surrogate key.

Comment: No. If the uid is not (a component of) the PK, don't use as an FK in other tables. Incidentally, you were taught wrong. A surrogate key isn't 'better' or 'worse'. However, if you do choose to use a surrogate key then, in general, you also have a UNIQUE natural key on one or a combination of other columns within the table.

Comment: To me it looks like `Uid` is also a surrogate key, no? Also, surrogate vs natural keys is a holy war, it's not clear which is better, so don't put too much thought into what you were taught.

Comment: Shall I drop Id and use Uid as PK or keep Id being my PK and after recieving Uid from client, find appropriate Id and work with it?

Comment: If you're not using your auto-increment PK, you can just drop it.  If you need an internal unique id later on, it's easy to add it back in.  It's also easy to swap foreign keys from one unique reference key to another.

Answer (score 1):

In general, I find that having auto-incremented primary keys is a good idea.

The problem of knowing "how many users you have" is irrelevant.  There is no reason to include the primary key in any external communication.  You can have the auto-incremented key, but use the uid for URLs and similar constructs.

You should, however, use the primary key for foreign key relationships with other tables.  There are significant performance advantages for the primary key.  You don't mention what `uid` really is.  But remember that many things can change over time.  For instance, if you are using an email address as a user id, the user's email address may change.

If you want a unique key that is not auto-incremented, then use the `uuid()` function.  You can use a universal identifier to both mask the user id and the number of users that you have.